# Extracting the polygons from a multi-polygon shapefile where they intercept with points from a multipoint shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have 2 shapefiles, one multi polygon shapefile (a) and and one multi-point shapefile (b).

I would like to extract the polygons from (a) only where they contain points from (b). I can do this pretty easily using the `Vector Selection` ---> `Extract by Location` in `QGIS`; however the attribute table from the output multi-polygon shapefile (c) **only** contains the information of the extracted polygons from (a) whereas I need them to retain the data from (b) as well.

Is there any way to create the output (c) but keep the information from both (a) and (b)?

I can add a step by using `Vector General` ----> `Join Attributes By Location`, however the attribute table from this output (d) has duplicates which I'd like to avoid. If, on the other hand, this added step is `Vector General` ---> `Join Attributes By Location` (Summary) there are no duplications in (d) but the new attribute table contains numerous summary statistics which I do not need, nor want.

Comment: Welome to GIS.SE! If one of your polygons contains more than 1 point and you tend to avoid duplicate polygons you need some statistical aggregation on your points attributes, me thinks? could you please clarify what kind of result you do expect for a polygon containing n points? and just an idea: isn't this a matter of data modelling, assigning the polygons id or slt. to the points and create a relation from your polygons to their belonging points?